# mount --bind vs mount: Mounting same device to multiple mountpoint

Tags: mount

*/dev/mapper/rhel-root* is already mounted as it's the root directory, so I tried to do experiment by mounting it again to another mountpoint.

Any difference between these two?

```
mount /dev/mapper/rhel-root <mountpoint A>

mount --bind / <mountpoint A>
```

Comment: Well, the second works fine, the first will most probably wreck your filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

`mount --bind` isn't limited to mountpoints which is its main advantage over a bare `mount`.

In this situation I'd use the bare `mount` since the bind would offer no advantages and might even be hassle in the long run.